# Alarm Manager not working when app is closed on a real device but works on an emulator- Xamarin Forms(Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I have been on this for about 3 days and I have not found anything to resolve my issue. What I seek to achieve is to receive notifications when the app is closed. I have tested it on my emulators and it works fine but does not work on real devices. The notifications work fine when the app is running in the foreground and when minimized. I use the alarm manager to trigger a receiver to then send the notification.

This is how I prep the alarm manager:

```
                alarmHandlerIntent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
                alarmHandlerIntent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);
                alarmHandlerIntent.PutExtra(DataKey, todo);
                alarmHandlerIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReceiverForeground);
                alarmHandlerIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.IncludeStoppedPackages);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(AndroidApp.Context, pendingIntentId++, alarmHandlerIntent, GetPendingIntentFlags());
                long triggerTime = GetNotifyTime(notifyTime.Value);
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
                {
                    alarmManager.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    alarmManager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
                }
```

and this is the GetPendingIntentFlags():

```
var pendingIntentFlags = (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.S)
                    ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable
                    : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;

return pendingIntentFlags;
```

This is the Receiver as well:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true, Label = "ToDo Local Notifications Broadcast Receiver")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted},
    Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class AlarmHandler : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent?.Extras != null)
        {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "BackgroundReceiver");
            wakeLock.Acquire();

            string title = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidNotificationManager.TitleKey);
            string message = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidNotificationManager.MessageKey);
            string data = intent.GetStringExtra(AndroidNotificationManager.DataKey);

            AndroidNotificationManager manager = AndroidNotificationManager.Instance ?? new AndroidNotificationManager();
            
            var status = new Todo
            {
                Id = data
            };

            MessagingCenter.Send(status, "TodoNotified", status);

            manager.Show(title, message, data);

            wakeLock.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the emulator and the physical device have the same android version? In addition, did you try to test it on different devices?

Comment: Yes, they have the same android version. and I have tested on multiple devices as well.

Comment: You can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186458/android-alarmmanager-is-not-working-after-app-is-closed) and try the solution in it.

Comment: Add function GetNotifyTime

Comment: @Style-7 I already have that added

Comment: I mean to the question.

Comment: That case did not resolve the issue @Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: According to that case, the cause seems to be the mobile phone manufacturers' settings in the android system. @DHacksHacks